apt: Search for graphical applications only
I am using Debian 12 and am looking for a graphical tool to try out regular expressions, and wanted to use apt to find one. When using apt search regex, I get many results - libraries, command line tools, gui tools. I am only interested in the GUI tools.
How can I filter the package list to only show graphical applications, and no libraries or other packages?

There are some maintenance issues with them, but debtags give this type of information. You can use them with aptitude:
aptitude search '~Ginterface::graphical regex'

This lists only regexxer and visual-regexp as expected.
apt-cache and apt don’t support tag-based searches; there’s an existing bug requesting tag support in apt-cache but it’s been open since 2007.

Too bad that "apt search" does not seem to support tags :(

Feature request for apt-cache, open since 2007: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=423373
